# Facebook SDK - Allday events

Tags: facebook, events

Is it possible to find out if a Facebook event is an allday event or a timed event?

Comment: This is not a place where you can search via Wikipedia, this is the place where you can ask your programming queries..

Comment: @ViralShah Search via Wikipedia? I do my searches with Google. Anyhow my searching did not produce any results that I was satisfied that's why I asked this question here since it is programming related.